Is thrust force on a pipe bend the same as using the pressure inside a pipe?
If I would like to calculate the thrust force on a pipe bend after pipe break, I would use linear momentum to determine the forces on the pipe bend.
But if I knew the pressure inside the pipe during the break event. Would I get the same forces by multiplying the pressure inside with the inner area of the pipe? For example, in the figure below. If I want the force on the pipe bend, instead of using linear momentum, could I use the inner pressure Pin times the bend area?


A diagram would be helpful to clarify where the pipe is being held and what region of the inner area you're referring to.

I've added a figure to the question.

Maybe I'm confusing terms, what I'm asking for is perhaps the thrust force from the fluid on the pipe bend. And if that is the same as taking the pressure inside the pipe bend Pin times the pipe bend area.

Consider pressurizing the piece of pipe shown in your diagram with the ends sealed, and setting it on a low-friction surface. Would it start accelerating laterally? Why or why not?

I asked a related question on this forum regarding the net force on a pipe bend. If there is a thickness on the pipe then I would say yes because the outer bend area is larger than the inner bend area? I'm not sure how this translates to this question though.

The answer you marked as "best answer" says that all the forces balance. I agree. Isolated objects don't suddenly accelerate away, regardless of how they're pressurized. So the product of the pressure and an area can't provide the force you're trying to calculate. You have to incorporate the momentum of the direction-changing fluid, as you noted in the beginning of your question.

The pressure varies with spatial position within the bend.  You would have to integrate the pressure force vectorially over the inside surface of the bend to get the resultant force.  Using the momentum balance eliminates the need to do this.
